# Using Exceptions to notify if the username is available or not

Tags: java, exception

let us say i'm having a table(login) that has usernames(unique key) and passwords, used for login purposes.

Now, in the registration module(that creates a new account by adding a new row in login table),is it okay if i just execute the insert and check if the username is already in the table when the SQLException() raises???. is it a good practice???

Here's an example of registration module:

```
enter code here
String uname = request.getParameter("username");
String passwd = request.getParameter("password");
try
{
  statement.executeUpdate("insert into login(username,password) values (" + uname + "," + passwd + ")");
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
   if((e.getErrorCode())==1) //error code when primary key violated
   {
      // username already exists....
   }    
   //some other code
 }

 //username is available....rest of the code goes here
```

in the firs place i thought of a select query to check if the username (user has entered while registering) is already in the table....but it seemed redundant to me

because i thought, even doing so wouldnt prevent the DBMS to check the uniqueness violation, right????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for "SQL injection attack" and "JDBC tutorial prepared statements". Your code is insecure.

Comment: always wanted to know how does these SQL injection attacks go,i'll check them...thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is do a validation before insert, in case you change underlying database which change the error code in [SQLException.getErrorCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29). This also enable you do validation before user submit the form. You can create a custom exception the notify your service caller that username is already in use.

> Retrieves the vendor-specific exception code for this SQLException
>   object.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME = :username
```

via a service method, for example:

```
public class UserService {

    public boolean isValidUsername(String username) {
        //validate
    }
    public void registerUser(User user) throws UsernameInUseException {
        if(!isValidUsername(user.getUsername()) {
            throw new UsernameInUseException("Usernaame " + user.getUsername() + " is already in use.");
        }
        // continue
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah i thoought of that too....but,see the edit i just did...hope u would understand that(i didnt frame it understandably,i guess)

Answer (score 0):

It will be cool if you could tell the user before form submission that username already exists using AJAX calls.

Comment: but right now forget about ajax....think of this as a GUI app(i mean not a web app) written in swings or whatever else...what do u think??

Comment: I agree with Pau Kiat Wee if that's the case.

Comment: in the firs place i thought of a select query to check if the username (user has entered while registering) is already in the table....but it seemed redundant to me

because i thought, even doing so wouldnt prevent the DBMS to check the uniqueness violation, right???? ,if yes, then the select query would consume a lot of time compared to the exception approach.If no, i want to know the problem with the exception approach.

Comment: Its technically not wrong to use the exception approach. Checking for duplication looks a cleaner approach. It entirely depends upon you what you want to use.